# How to create a drawing zone on Android

Tags: android, draw

I'm working on an app and i need to catch the signing of the client (on an Android tablet) and i don't know how to create a drawing zone and to save the signing once it's done.
If you have some good practices or ideas you're welcome.

Comment: I suggest you look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html
Basically you could make a custom control that records the areas you touched and draws itself accordingly. But there might be a less "manual" way (not sure)

Comment: You can try looking into the GestureOverlayView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a custom view and track the onTouch events.  A good tutorial is here http://corner.squareup.com/2010/07/smooth-signatures.html  describing how Square does it for credit card signatures